# Why my RectangleWidget isn't Fullscreen

Tags: python, kivy

I just start Kivy programming and have a problem with the understanding of doing a layout:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color

class CornerRectangleWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CornerRectangleWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 1, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(size_hint=(1,None),height=48)

class ControllerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 0, 0, 1)
        root = FloatLayout(size_hint=(1,1))
        root.add_widget(CornerRectangleWidget())
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ControllerApp().run()
```

Why is my CornerRectangleWidget keeping so small. I wanted to have a FloatLayout with Fullscreen and the CornerRectangleWidget too.

Actually I want to build the Widget "CornerRectangleWidget" to a floating top Toolbar with the x dimensins of the root Widget "FloatLayout size_hint=(1,None)"! How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectangle doesn't have a size_hint, you need to set a pos and size.

You'll also need to bind to a function to update its position when the widget position changes, as during the `__init__` it will have the default pos of (0, 0) and size of (100, 100). This is described [here](http://inclem.net/2014/10/10/kivy/kivy_update_instructions/).